# Polymorphic result type GADT function

Tags: haskell, types, gadt

In the following code, what can I replace `x = ...`. Note that I don't want to put a class restriction on `a` (of course, `a` is of kind `Bool` already anyway so can only take one of two types).

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

data D (a :: Bool) where
  D1 :: D True
  D2 :: D False

x :: D a
x = ...
```

Basically, with GADTs like this it's easy to do polymorphism on the input (just match on the appropriate constructors) but I want to use polymorphism in the output.

Comment: This is impossible, there is no way to return a polymorphic value in `D a`, unless it's bottom. If/when we get `pi` types (non-erased types), then it will be possible to write `x :: pi a. D a`

Comment: Also, as unpleasant as it is, `D Any` is a valid type. `DataKinds` still allows type-level undefined...

Comment: I don't mind that being undefined, as long as `x :: D True` and `x :: D False` are defined.

Comment: GHC has no knowledge that `a :: Bool` can  only be `True` or `False`. Dispatching on `a :: Bool` is not possible in any way, since it's erased at runtime. You need at least `x :: SingI a => D a` or `x :: Sing a -> D a` if you want dispatch.

Comment: If `a` is erased at runtime, how does dispatch work for class methods? Or is the type saved for types with class constraints?

Comment: @Clinton Explicit dictionaries are passed, and types are erased.  For example, for something like `Show a => a -> IO ()`, it's more or less implemented as `(a -> String) -> a -> IO ()`.  The actual class method implementations themselves are passed in as arguments, so the types don't have to.

Answer (score 9):

This requires dependent types - there is no way around it. In Idris, a Haskell-like dependently typed language you can write this just fine:

```
data D : Bool -> Type where
  D1 : D True
  D2 : D False

-- The `{ .. }` mean the argument is inferred.
x : {a : Bool} -> D a
x {a = True} = D1
x {a = False} = D2
```

In Haskell, the only way you can dispatch based on type at runtime is through type classes, so you need a constraint. In fact, as @András points out there is [`SingI`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.2/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:SingI) that is made for this (it comes from a package [`singletons`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) which deals exactly with this sort of problem).

In your case, that would be:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, TypeInType, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Singletons.Prelude   

data D (a :: Bool) where
  D1 :: D True
  D2 :: D False

x :: forall a. SingI a => D a
x = case sing :: Sing a of
      STrue -> D1
      SFalse -> D2
```

It might be worth mentioning that although there is a `SingI` constraint, it has all of the appropriate instances already defined with it. Anything else that is a valid `D` type but not with a `Bool` argument (like `D Any`) fails at compile time (there is simply no `SingI` instance found).

```
ghci> let _ = x :: D True
ghci> let _ = x :: D False
ghci> let _ = x :: D Any
<interactive> error:
  • No instance for (SingI Any) arising from a use of ‘x’
  • In the expression: x :: D Any
    In a pattern binding: _ = x :: D Any
```

Comment: This answer would be improved with a demonstration of the type class technique.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Updated accordingly.